# Cascading deletes like ON DELETE CASCADE for a one time operation in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

Is there some sort of magical SQL statement to delete a row and all its dependents (linked by foreign key constraints) **WITHOUT** altering the table to add `ON DELETE CASCADE` or deleting each dependent row manually?

I am fantasizing something such as `` DELETE FROM `table_a` WHERE `id` = 1 ON DELETE CASCADE; `` but I can't seem to find anything to this effect in the doc @ http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/delete.html

- I don't want to `ALTER` the table to change the constraints for just a one time operation and then revert it back using another `ALTER`
- I don't want to execute something like `` DELETE FROM `table_b` WHERE `a_id` = 1; `` for each table containing a FK to `table_a`

Using MySQL 5.5 with InnoDB

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, the simple answer is, no, there is no shortcut.

You either write down `DELETE` statements to delete all the related rows in the related tables or you have defined foreign key constraints with `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

Note that - as long as there are no circular paths in the foreign key relationships - it is possible to use a single `DELETE` statement that deletes from multiple tables:

```
DELETE a, b, c, d
FROM a
  LEFT JOIN b  ON  b.a_id = a.a_id
  LEFT JOIN c  ON  c.a_id = a.a_id
  LEFT JOIN d  ON  d.b_id = b.b_id 
WHERE
    a.a_id = 1 ;
```

Comment: What a bummer... anyway I forgot about using a single DELETE statement with JOINs, thanks for suggesting that.

Comment: Unfortunately, as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6881990/1458112) and in the mysql [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/delete.html), there is no way to control the order of the deletions, so this might still fail. Which I just learned the hard way...